# Error in Ops.factor(actual, predicted) : level sets of factors are different with Featureimp from package iml

Tags: r, machine-learning

I'm working with the dataset "creditcard" from Kaggle. I used randomforest for a prediction and for the training set I used the smot function for balance my data.
I have a problem with the package iml for interpretation machine Learning: when I use the function "FeatureImp" for my model it gives me an error:

> Error in Ops.factor(actual, predicted): level sets of factors are different.

What have I to do for solving the problem and start working with iml?

The variable for prediction is class: `factor = 0/1`. I already control the class of Class variable and it's factor. I used the loss function "ce" in FeatureImp.

```
library(DMwR)

smote_creditcard <- SMOTE(Class ~ ., creditcard_train, k=10, perc.over=400,perc.under = 50)

#con perc.over=100 praticamente raddoppio i casi della classe minore

table(smote_creditcard$Class)

#   0    1 
# 796 1990 

prop.table(table(smote_creditcard$Class))

smote_creditcard$Class<-as.factor(smote_creditcard$Class)

creditcard_random <- randomForest(formula = Class ~ ., 
                                  data = smote_creditcard,ntree=1000,mtry=5)

library(iml)

X<-smote_creditcard[which(names(smote_creditcard)!="Class")]

y<-smote_creditcard$Class

predictor<-Predictor$new(creditcard_random,data=X,y=y,type="prob")

imp<-FeatureImp$new(predictor,loss="ce")
```

Error in Ops.factor(actual, predicted) : 
  level sets of factors are different

Comment: Seems you've different levels in the predicted and actual values, try to use `levels()`on them to know it.

Comment: 0

 
levels(predict(creditcard_random,smote_creditcard)) levels(smote_creditcard$Class)
I think is the right code that you adviced me. The output is the same and is : "0" "1".

Answer (score 0):

```
levels(predict(creditcard_random,smote_creditcard)) levels(smote_creditcard$Class)
```

I think is the right code that you adviced me. The output is the same and is :
"0" "1".

Comment: Please, edit your question, do not use an answer in a wrong way.